# Getting multiples of a value in swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to check if a number is a multiple of 3 or 5 or both in which different vaues would be printed. I am able to get the values running but checking for both does not seem to give the expected result.

here is my code and response

```
func fizzBuzz(n: Int) -> Void {
    let value = n
    for i in 1...value{
        if(i.isMultiple(of: 5)){
            print("Buzz")
        } else if(i.isMultiple(of: 3)){
            print("Fizz")
        } else if (i.isMultiple(of: 5)) && (i.isMultiple(of: 3)){
            return print("FizzBuzz")
        } else {
            print(i)
        }
    }

}

fizzBuzz(n: 15)
```

the response

```
1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
Fizz
7
8
Fizz
Buzz
11
Fizz
13
14
Buzz
```

Comment: Simply that is it's multiple of BOTH, then the first if will be triggered before triggering the dual check. Check firstly if it's mutliple of both.

Comment: Thanks @Larme that was the problem

Comment: Also, checking for both multiples of 3 and 5 identical to checking if it's multiple of 15

Comment: Please update your goal response

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/33975661/2303865

Answer (score 1):

**Check first multiple of both**

```swift
func fizzBuzz(n: Int) -> Void {
    for i in 1...n {
        if i.isMultiple(of: 15) {
            print("FizzBuzz")
        } else if i.isMultiple(of: 5) {
            print("Buzz")
        } else if i.isMultiple(of: 3) {
            print("Fizz")
        } else {
            print(i)
        }
    }
}

fizzBuzz(n: 15)
```

**Response**

```
1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
Fizz
7
8
Fizz
Buzz
11
Fizz
13
14
FizzBuzz
```

Comment: `isMultiple` is already part of standard library in Swift 5

Comment: @user28434 you are right :) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/3127688-ismultiple

Answer (score 1):

#### Here is the answer based on the above.

```
func fizzBuzz(n: Int) {

    let value = n

    for i in 1...value {

        // The number is multiple of 3 and 5
        if (i.isMultiple(of: 15)) {
            print("FizzBuzz")
        }
        // The number is multiple of 5
        else if(i.isMultiple(of: 5)){
            print("Buzz")
        }
        // The number is multiple of 3
        else if(i.isMultiple(of: 3)){
            print("Fizz")
        }
        else {
            print(i)
        }
    }
}

fizzBuzz(n: 15)
```