# How to find all numbers divisible by another number in swift?

Tags: swift, fizzbuzz

How do I find all the numbers divisible by another number in swift that have a remainder of 0? This is a Fizzbuzz related question.

Lets say that...

```
let number = 150
```

And I want to do something like...

```
print("Fizz") // for all the numbers where the remainder of number % 3 == 0.
```

So if number was 15, it would print "Fizz" 5 times.

Comment: you want to loop through all number?

Comment: You are playing "Fizz buzz"? – See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279000/switch-statement-in-swift!

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
let number = 150

for num in 1...number {
    if num % 3 == 0 {
        print("Fizz :\(num)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can just loop through the number and check with your desired divisible number if the remainder is 0 then print `fizz`

```
let number = 15

for i in 0..<number {
    if i % 3 == 0 {
        print("\(i) Fizz")
    }
}
```

It will print Fizz 5 times with the i value, that which number is Fizz.

Answer (score -1):

**Simply try this code:** (You can simply replace **num** with any **Int** number and **divider** that is also an **Int** value which is used to divide all numbers till **num**. )

```
override func viewDidLoad() { 
      let num:Int = 15
      let divider:Int = 3
      var counter:Int = divider
      while counter <= num {
         print("Fizz")
         counter += divider
      }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
func fizzbuzz(number: Int) -> String {
    if number % 3 == 0 && number % 5 == 0 {
        return "Fizz Buzz"
    } else if number % 3 == 0 {
        return "Fizz"
    } else if number % 5 == 0 {
        return "Buzz"
    } else {
        return String(number)
    }
}
```

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/guide/ios-classic/1/3/challenge