# In Swift, why is this equals operator in this conditional even necessary?

Tags: swift, xcode, logic

The code below works so I am not asking for a solution.
My question is why `== 0`  is even necessary?

Thank you

```
for i in 1...100 {
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        print("Fizz")
    } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
        print("Buzz")
    } else if (i % 3 == 0) && (i % 5 == 0) {
        print("Fizz Buzz")
    } else {
        print(i)
    }
}
```

Comment: Swift's `if` requires a `Bool` statement and an `Int` isn't treated like a `Bool` like it is in `C`.  So, it's due to Swift's stronger type checking, which isn't necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: Btw, your logic is wrong, for the number 15 it prints "Fizz" instead of "Fizz Buzz". – See also [Switch statement in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279000/switch-statement-in-swift) for some "swiftier" solutions.

Comment: Ok but I'm why   == 0   , is even necessary? If I try this without it the code fails.

Comment: Why not just (i % 3) {      instead of (i % 3) == 0) {

Comment: @SilentMonk Because the type of `(i % 3)` is `Int`. Comparing `(i % 3 == 0)` is a boolean expression whose type is `Bool`. The if-statement can only have a condition whose type is `Bool`, unlike in C where the condition can be of type `Int` (where 0 is considered `false` and anything else is considered `true`).