# Solving Fizz Buzz using a switch statement & tuple

Tags: swift, switch-statement, tuples, fizzbuzz

I am working through the 'Big Nerd Ranch Swift Programming 2nd edition guide book' and am stuck on a silver challenge at the end of chapter 6 - loops

The challenge asks to solve Fizz Buzz with both an if/else conditional and a switch statement, and when using the switch, making sure to match against a tuple in its various cases.

I solved the if/else conditional using a while loop and several nested if else statements without any issues, however I am stuck on the switch implementation of this challenge.

I have tried using a while loop with a switch inside and the playground does not compile. I have not found any answers directly relating to my situation so here is the code I have implemented that does not seem to work.

```
var n: Int = 0
var i: Int = 0
while i <= 100 {

switch (n % 3 == 0, n % 5 == 0) {
case (true, false):
    print("Fizz")
case (false, true):
    print("Buzz")
case (true, true):
    print("FizzBuzz")
default:
    print("\(n)")
}

n += 1
i += 1
}
```

The challenge is to use a tuple and a switch but I cannot figure out how to make this work for the life of me.

**This situation has been solved.... the problem for me seemed to be needing to restart xcode... very irritating considering I spent a few hours tinkering with code to try and get this to work. I probably have tried 4 different successful iterations of this challenge but didn't realize it because xcode needed to be restarted :( Thank you to those who confirmed it compiled and ran successfully which prompted me to try restarting xcode. This situation makes learning swift and xcode difficult**

Comment: Your code compiles and runs, and you are matching agains tuples. What is the question? (An alternative implementation is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25280179/1187415)

Comment: What is the issue? It is working fine for me.

Comment: When I run this code in playgrounds on xcode, it does not run, it seems to infinitely compile?

Comment: For me same code runs 101 times exactly. No infinite loop. I am also trying in playground

Comment: What could be wrong? I suppose I could restart xcode and see if that solves my issue... but all it says in the status bar at the top is "Running ...." with the spinning wheel animation next to it :(

Comment: Restarting xcode solved this issue... that is very troubling as a new person trying to learn swift and xcode :\