# automatically define current index

Tags: ios, swift

I have a controller with buttons and a `TableViewController` with 10 arrays. Each button has an index, which pass to `TableViewController`.

In `TableViewController` code looks like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(format: "cell", indexPath.row), for: indexPath)

    if buttonIndex == 0 {
        label?.text = array0[indexPath.row]
    }
    else if buttonIndex == 1 {
        label?.text = array1[indexPath.row]
    }
    else if buttonIndex == 2 {
        label?.text = array2[indexPath.row]
    }
    else if buttonIndex == 3 {
        label?.text = array3[indexPath.row]
    }
    else if buttonIndex == 4 {
        label?.text = array4[indexPath.row]
    }
    else if buttonIndex == 5 {
        label?.text = array5[indexPath.row]
    }
    else if buttonIndex == 6 {
        label?.text = array6[indexPath.row]
    }
    else if buttonIndex == 7 {
        label?.text = array6[indexPath.row]
    }
    else if buttonIndex == 8 {
        label?.text = array6[indexPath.row]
    }

}
```

I want to automatically define current index to do this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(format: "cell", indexPath.row), for: indexPath)
        //label?.text = array(currentIndex[indexPath.row]
    }
```

How to do it?

Comment: Why don't you do: `let array = [array0, array1, etc.]`. And `label?.text = array[buttonIndex][indexPath.row]` or something like that?

Comment: As an aside, you might consider refactoring your if statements to switch: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279000/switch-statement-in-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot generate variable names dynamically since they have to be known in runtime.

One feasible solution is to put the arrays in another array and access the individual arrays through their indexes in the array of arrays.

```
let allArrays: [[Any]] = [array0,array1,...]

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(format: "cell", indexPath.row), for: indexPath)
    label?.text = allArrays[buttonIndex][indexPath.row]
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's the *only* solution, but it's a good, clean solution. (voted)

Comment: Right, I changed the wording, it might have been a bit too restrictive. Thanks.

Comment: `self.value(forKeyPath:"array\(buttonIndex)")` doesn't return the target array? At some minor issue fix (not a Swift Expert).

Comment: Key-value coding is only available from Swift4 as far as I know. And why would you need to do that? You can just subscript the array as it is shown in my question.

Comment: @Larme That's not a Swift API and is generally avoided in Swifty code

Comment: @DávidPásztor I get issue in this line `label?.text = array[buttonIndex][indexPath.row]` unresolved identifier 'array' if I use this line `label?.text = allArrays[buttonIndex][indexPath.row]` I get this issue Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Comment: `let allArrays:[[Any]] = [array0,array1,...]` should do the trick. and `array` instead of `allArray` is a typo in the answer. @AllenHumphreys I avoid it too in Objective-C, but it was to rebound on Duncan comment "not the only solution".

Comment: @user fixed the typo for the array name and added a type annotation for allArrays. If your inner arrays all contain the same type (I guess it's `String`, since you use it as a label's text), change the type annotation to [[String]] or whatever their type is.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dictionary for it, that's the recommended way. 
After all your arrays have been successfully created, simply append them like that:

```
let arrayDictionary = [Int:[String]]
let index = yourIndex 
arrayDictionary[index] = arrayWithIndex
```

Then you can call

```
if button.index == theIndex {
  let unwrappedArray = arrayDictionary[theIndex]
  label.text = unwrappedArray[indexPath.row]
}
```

That's the cleanest solution.